# is there a way to render a Pdf Form with functionally fields in android app?

Tags: java, android, forms, pdf

is there a way to render a Pdf Form with functionally fields in android app?
Already Rendered a pdf file in my application, but what I want is to fill it, because it is a PDF Form, with text and list picking fields, alredy use iTextPdf library to manage the fields, but still don't know, how to show the pdf form in the app, with PdfRenderer I could get just an print of the pages but no the form to actually fill it.
This is my code by now...

```
private void viewPdf(){

    // create a new renderer

     image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
     int REQ_WIDHT =getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getWidth();
     int REQ_HEIGHT =getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getHeight();

     Bitmap bitmap= Bitmap.createBitmap(REQ_WIDHT, REQ_HEIGHT, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
     //File file = new File("/assets/form1_pdf.pdf");
    try {

        PdfRenderer renderer = new PdfRenderer( this.getApplicationContext().getAssets().openFd("form1_pdf.pdf").getParcelFileDescriptor());
        //Matrix m = image.getImageMatrix();
        Rect rect = new Rect(0,0,REQ_WIDHT, REQ_HEIGHT);
        renderer.openPage(0).render(bitmap, null, null, PdfRenderer.Page.RENDER_MODE_FOR_DISPLAY);
        //image.setImageMatrix(m);

        // calculate the scale - in this case = 0.4f
        float scaleWidth = ((float) REQ_HEIGHT) / REQ_WIDHT;
        float scaleHeight = ((float) REQ_WIDHT) / REQ_HEIGHT;

        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
        matrix.postRotate(90);

        Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,REQ_WIDHT, REQ_HEIGHT, matrix, true);
        image.setImageBitmap(resizedBitmap);
        image.invalidate();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        e.getMessage();
    }


}
```